# Reference different tables depending on a condition

Tags: sql, database-design, referential-integrity

I have a table `[Advertiser]` and a table `[Ad]` that has a `N..M` relationship that an `Advertiser` can have many `Ads` so that `[Ad]` will have a column referncing `[Advertiser]`.

An `Advertiser` can either be a **company** or a **person** and the data entered into the table will differ depending. So my thought was that I should split up the `[Advertiser]` table into two tables like `[CompanyAdvertiser]` and `[PersonAdvertiser]`.

Is it then possible to have a column in `[Ad]` having a reference to either `[CompanyAdvertiser]` or `[PersonAdvertiser]` depending on who should be the `Advertiser`?

Comment: Assuming they have the same type, you can have such a column.  But you cannot have foreign key relationships using that column to two different tables.

Comment: are you OK with having a solution for particular RDMS? Tag it, if so.

Comment: Just have a column for advertiser_type, company or person, in the advertiser table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having one table Advertiser with a 'type' column that could be either 'person' or 'company'. Then add reference to this table in Ad table